# Trouble proving that $\cup \{x\}=x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> [image]

The definition of union is given as:

> [image]

I am a bit confused: Looking at the definition, I think $\mathcal{F}=\{x\}$, then we take $A\in \mathcal{F}$ and then, we have only one possibility $A=x$ then we take $t\in A =x$ but this doesn't seems to yield $x$.

On the other hand, if we consider $\mathcal{F}=\{\{x\}\}$, then we take $A\in \mathcal{F}$ and then we have $A=\{x\}$ then we take $t\in A =\{x\}$ and now we have $t=x$ and hence the ouput $\{x\}$ which is also not what is pointed in the question.

What am I missing?

Comment: The definition of union is a bit ambiguous, indeed if you take $\cup \{x\} \triangleq \{y : y \in B \ \text{for some} B \in {x}\}$ But in this meaning have to be precised what is here a singleton. Otherwise  we cannont have $ y \in B$ is this set theory doesn't consider $x$ as a set.

Comment: $x\in\{x\}=x\implies x\in x$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen It's relatively common to define $\bigcup S$ to be short for $\bigcup_{s\in S}s$. There's no confusing elements with singleton sets here -- this is set theory, so *everything* is a set and it's fair to take $\bigcup x$ no matter the $x$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen No, [the notation is pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union#Formal_statement).

Answer (score 2):

$u\in \bigcup \{x\} \text{ iff } \exists t\in \{x\} \text{ and } u\in t \text{ iff } t=x \text{ and } u\in t \text{ iff } u\in x$, so $\bigcup \{x\}=x$.

Comment: Aren't you saying that $x\in x$? Coldn't it also be the case that $x \not \in x$?

Comment: No, I am not.  I am comparing the elements of $\bigcup\{x\}$ and $x$. So, by definition of union, if $u$ is in such union, then it has to belong to some element of $\{x\}$, then $u\in x$.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the only possibility for $A$ is $x$. Then $\displaystyle{\bigcup\{x\}}$ is the union of the elements of $x$, which is just $x$. Recall that $x$ is a set, so it is a thing where we have notions like "the union of its elements."

Colloquially, $\displaystyle{\bigcup x}$ is the set of elements inside of elements of $x$. Say that $x$ is a singleton $\{y\}$. Then $\displaystyle{\bigcup x=y}$ from the first part, so $\displaystyle{\left\{\bigcup x\right\}=\{y\}=x}$. Furthermore, if $x$ is not a singleton, then since $\displaystyle{\left\{\bigcup x\right\}}$ is a singleton it cannot be equal to $x$.